# Php array posts make max value output

Tags: php, arrays

I want this shopping cart number of item to count. The post is different value is different. Please make it this code shorten and unlimited post can manage easily get the max value of number of items.

```
    if($_POST['item_number_9']==9){$y=9;}
elseif($_POST['item_number_8']==8){$y=8;}
elseif($_POST['item_number_7']==7){$y=7;}
elseif($_POST['item_number_6']==6){$y=6;}
elseif($_POST['item_number_5']==5){$y=5;}
elseif($_POST['item_number_4']==4){$y=4;}
elseif($_POST['item_number_3']==3){$y=3;}
elseif($_POST['item_number_2']==2){$y=2;}
elseif($_POST['item_number_1']==1){$y=1;}

echo $y; //9 is max value of array
// i want this code to be array and $y is maximum post
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the max function](http://php.net/max)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $key =>$entrie){
  if(strpos($key, "item_number_") === 0){
    $y = $entrie;
  }
}
```

This goes through all the `$_POST` elements. if they are something with `item_number_` the value is set into `$y`. This asumes that there is only one entrie in `$_POST` with `item_number_` in it, as there should be only one entrie that holds the number of items in the cart.

---

But offerall this is bad practise. you should set only `$_POST['item_number']` and hold the number of items in that.